# Inverting regression discontinuity assumptions: is this a valid approach?

Tags: regression-discontinuity

A key assumption of regression discontinuity designs is that respondents have little to no control over assignment. I inverted this assumption to test whether reductions in workers' compensation payments that occur several months into the process cause injured workers to leave the system early (preprint [here](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/19012286v1)). So, it's less about assignment to a condition than response to a potential assignment. While I raised this as a limitation, one of the reviewers quite reasonably asked whether this is appropriate. **My question is whether this inversion of the assumption invalidates the study design, or if it just requires greater care in interpretation. And, has any other study done this?**

My thought is that it just requires extra care in interpretation. For instance, I found that there was a negative effect, which is illustrated in the attached figure (note, the lack of fitted lines in some states mean there were insufficient data). A naive interpretation - that a regression discontinuity simulates a randomised trial and I'm comparing a pre step-down "control" to a post-step-down "exposed" - would take that as evidence that the reduction in compensation caused people to stay on the system longer, which is contrary to all that is known about workers' compensation. A more considered interpretation would raise an anticipatory response: injured workers are aware of the impending reduction and leave the system early to avoid the loss of payment. Indeed, the attached figure indicates scheme exit increases just before step-downs come into effect. Is this a sufficient way to address this problem, or is there more I must consider?

[image: Illustration of step-down effect]